# Power Query and Staging

Tags: excel

I have installed Power Query and can access my production environment.  I cannot log into our staging environment.  The PW is the same in both environments.  I'm wondering if the token the same in both staging and production? Or if Power Query is built for staging? It seems to default to the https://login.salesforce.com/ domain.

Comment: If you can't change the URL to test.salesforce.com, then you won't be able to use  PowerQuery with any sandboxes.  If you do a web search you'll find a few message posts about power query and salesforce sandboxes.